Extract yield volatility from bond option prices
Is there a way to extract yield volatility from bond option prices or to convert implied bond prices to yield volatility?

Do you have bond option prices? There aren't listed, just OTC and very illiquid. If you do have prices, Bloomberg's OVME solves for yield and price vol.

Thanks. Do you know how Bloomberg do that?

It's something like yield * yield vol * risk / underlying_Price, where risk is DV01 as seen on YAS.

You will need a Bond Option Pricing Formula which uses the yield volatility.
There is another question around Bond option on price vs bond option on yield
So, the payoff of your bond option is
$(K_P-P_T)^+ = (Y_T - Y_K)^+ \cdot (-P'_y)$
You assume normal yield distribution, use the Bachelier formula and imply the yield volatility.
See this answer as well: Bachelier model call option pricing formula
